# Hystrix Command Objects : new vs singleton

Tags: multithreading, singleton, threadpool, hystrix, command-pattern

Is it correct to create `HystrixCommand` object implementations as Singleton? 
If it does, is it going to hold the thread till it finishes execution and won't create anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> No, they are executed only once. They are stateful with input arguments, response value or error and request log. (c) [Hystrix github](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/198)